# Targeting child pages of custom post types using function?

Tags: custom-post-types

I had this old piece of code from [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/if-page-is-parent-or-child/) that was for making it so I could conditionally target child pages of a parent. It worked great until I changed my content to a custom post type. Now the code no longer works, as it was specifically for pages.

```
    function is_tree($pid) { // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
        global $post; // load details about this page
        if(is_page()&&($post->post_parent==$pid||is_page($pid))) 
          return true; // we're at the page or at a sub page
        else 
          return false; // we're elsewhere
    };
```

I adapted it, now using is_singular('post_type'). The problem is that it always seems to meet the first condition and never hits the second elseif. I can't seem to figure out why exactly it isn't working.

```
    function is_tree($pid) {  
        global $post; 
        if(is_singular('guides' )&&($post->post_parent==$pid||is_singular( 'guides', $pid ))) 
          return true;   
        else 
          return false;  
    };
```

Any idea on what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_singular` only accepts one argument- post type. It's only for checking if a post is of a certain type(s), not a specific post of that type. Check `$post->ID` instead-

```
if(is_singular('guides' )&&($post->post_parent==$pid||$post->ID==$pid))
```

I would also consider using `get_queried_object()` and/or `get_queried_object_id()` rather than use the global `$post`.

Comment: Perfect, that seems to have worked. Now for the get_queried_object, how do use that in this context? I tried just replacing global get_queried_object_id() and got an error and none of the documentation I've read seems to match this context(sorry not a developer here).